# URL Rewriting not working in global.aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, global-asax

I want to make some friendlyurls in my ASP.Net C# project and I'm trying to do this in `global.asax` file and `protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)` but I am getting error in in browser. it is not working. I am attaching screenshot and pasting code also with this.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
        static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("Dashboard", "{FullName}-{Id}/Dashboard", "~/Dashboard.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Reviews", "{FullName}-{Id}/Reviews", "~/Reviews.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Events", "{FullName}-{Id}/Events", "~/Events.aspx");
        }
```

This is my code that i am using in my `global.aspx` file under the `Application_Start` method. by using this code, it is making url correct but not redirecting on any page and showing error is The: `localhost page isn’t working`
    localhost redirected you too many times.
this error i am getting on the browser while i am running my project.
[image: Global.aspx page code screenshot is here]
[image: Error page in the browser]

This is my problem please anyone resolve this problem and help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just a stab...Not too sure if you can have parameters "dash" separated...have you tried.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Dashboard", "{FullName}/{Id}/Dashboard", "~/Dashboard.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Reviews", "{FullName}/{Id}/Reviews", "~/Reviews.aspx");
            routes.MapPageRoute("Events", "{FullName}/{Id}/Events", "~/Events.aspx");
```

Also, your path is `localhost/user/<URL Route>...`not too sure if it will work without the rest of the path in the `routes`.
Can you confirm your landing pages are being hit (put break in `page_load`)?